# how to prevent html checkboxes, radiogroups and textarea reset if submit is unsuccessful

Tags: php, html, checkbox, radio-button, reset

I am using a form to register the user on my website and i have a captcha security on it. Everything is working well and good but the only problem that i am facing is that if i enter a wrong captcha or somehow the page refreshes , all the data entered by the user is wiped out.

i now know how to prevent text fields from reset but i still need to know how to do the same for checkboxes, radiogroups and textarea.

what i wish to achieve is that even if the captcha entered is wrong and the form is submitted , the form should have checkboxes, radiogroups and textarea as the user filled in excluding the captcha field such as to save time of the user in refilling the form.

How can this be done? My form is html and the processing page is php

Comment: store the choices in php and transport them to the output so that the form is filled with already entered values. there are html tags like value=..." or checked="checked" for radio boxes to use for this.

Comment: Can you please provide me with an example?

Comment: you are getting the data with the $_POST array or input filter functions in php, right? well if the captcha is wrong update the form that will be displayed to contain the data the user entered and maybe html escape it against xss.

Comment: yes i am getting the data with $_POST , but how to apply them to checkboxes and select menus

Comment: how is your form generated? is it a plain htm file where you can insert php content to? you might include it to pass the content or store the content of the form submit in session data for further usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="yes" <?php echo ($_POST['agree']=='yes' ? 'checked="checked"' : '');?> />
```

Comment: what about textarea and select menu?

Comment: <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="43" rows="6"><?php echo (isset($_POST['comments']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['comments']) : ''); ?></textarea>

Answer (score 0):

Examples for a few inputs, the monitor on top of the script should give a clue for other inputs:

```
<?php
/*monitor the POST request, delete in production*/
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    //check things like captcha / empty fields first, 
    //if something fails: fill variables
    $postedText     = isset($_POST['textInput']) ? $_POST['textInput'] : null;
    $postedCheckbox = isset($_POST['checkboxInput']) ? 1 : 0;
    $postedRadio    = isset($_POST['radioInput']) ? $_POST['radioInput'] : null;
    $postedSelect   = $_POST['selectInput'];
    $postedTextarea = isset($_POST['textareaInput']) ? $_POST['textareaInput'] : null;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <label for="textInput">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" 
                   id="textInput" 
                   name="textInput" 
                   value="<?php echo (isset($postedText) ? $postedText : 'text') ;?>"
                   />
            <br />
            <label for="checkboxInput">Checkbox:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" 
                   id="checkboxInput" 
                   name="checkboxInput" 
                   <?php echo (isset($postedCheckbox) && $postedCheckbox === 1 ? "checked='checked'" : '') ;?>
                   />
            <br />
            <label for="rbInput">Radio:</label>
            <input type="radio" 
                   id="rbInputMale" 
                   name="rbInput" 
                   value="male"
                   <?php echo (isset($postedRadio) && $postedRadio === 'male' ? "checked='checked'" : '') ;?>
                   /> male
            <input type="radio" 
                   id="rbInputFemale" 
                   name="rbInput" 
                   value="female"
                   <?php echo (isset($postedRadio) && $postedRadio === 'female' ? "checked='checked'" : '') ;?>
                   /> female
            <br />
            <label for="selectInput">Select</label>
            <select name="selectInput"
                    id="selectInput">
                <?php
                $options    = array(
                    'one'   => 'one',
                    'two'   => 'two',
                    'three' => 'three'
                );
                foreach ($options as $key => $value)
                {
                    ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value;?>"
                        <?php 
                        if(isset($postedSelect))
                        {
                            echo ($value === $postedSelect ? "selected='selected'" : '');
                        }
                            ?>
                        >
                            <?php echo $key;?>
                </option>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br />
            <label for="textareaInput">textarea</label>
            <textarea name="textareaInput" id="textareaInput"><?php echo (isset($postedTextarea) ? $postedTextarea : '');?></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```